# Is there a way to restart in Windows 8 using fast startup?

Tags: windows-8, boot, reboot

In Windows 8 shutting down and starting up again uses the new Fast Startup feature, reducing the boot time. Restarting uses the original cold boot behavior.

I work in a dual boot environment where Windows is not my main or default OS. I switch from Windows more than I switch to it. When doing so I often trigger a restart in Windows to load my main OS, but the next Windows boot time will be slower as restart was last used.

Is there a way to combine the two, where one restarts the computer but the next boot is a fast boot? I presume any such methods would not modify Windows' restart functionality, as a cold boot has its merits. Perhaps setting some sort of "restart flag", so that after completing the hybrid shutdown, a restart is triggered. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 5):

The fast boot feature takes a 'snapshot' of system files currently in memory and stores them on the hard disk (similar to how hibernation works), ready to load those files straight back into memory once turned on again - instead of going through the entire boot sequence again to generate these files. This is what gives you that quick effect when starting up using this feature. However, when you select to restart, it is assumed that you want to completely close down the system and start fresh. Therefore it performs a close down sequence on all system files in memory.

It does not make logical sense to perform a restart with the fast boot feature enabled. The purpose of a restart is not just to remove currently active files in memory, but to also provide a clean canvas for the operating system, and other applications, to apply updates. Updates cannot be applied if critical files are in use, therefore having the requirement to close *everything*, apply changes, and reopen critical files.

You (or the system) will not achieve anything from restarting with the fast boot feature enabled (if it is possible), compared to shutting down and turning on again with the fast boot feature enabled. The only benefit you will gain is that it will close all currently open applications.

Whilst I've answered this question with little research for you, as I've presumed you've done your research already, I will confidently hazard a guess and say this isn't possible. If you want to close all open applications and free up memory, look into alternative means for memory management, or simply close down and turn on again.

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not possible. Hibernate expects the system state to stay the same. If another operating system mounts the file system, however, the state is changed, making the hibernate snapshot invalid. This could also lead to serious file system corruption.